# click handler not toggling state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a simple app where if you click on a button, a modal overlay appears, and if you click on the 'x' in the modal it disappears.
I made a component for my button, called ShowOffer, and I have an onclick on it which toggles the boolean value of modalVisible, which is a piece of state.
However, nothing happens when I click on it.
I made another button element with the same onclick, and it seems to work fine.
Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-fire-tnis9?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You have to pass `onClick` props inside `ShowOffer` and add `<div onClick={onClick}>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `onClick` on the `ShowOffer` component, but here you are just passing it as a `prop` in it.

```
<ShowOffer display={"block"} onClick={toggleVisibility} />
```

is same as

```
React.createElement(ShowOffer, {
  display: "block",
  onClick: toggleVisibility
});
```

Under the hook, you are just passing an argument to a function

You have to add `onClick` event on the `button` in `ShowOffer` component as:

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
<button
      style={{ display: `${display}` }}
      onClick={toggleVisibility}
      className="show-offer"
    >
      Show Offer
    </button>
```

and you have to pass the `toggleVisibility` callback to `ShowOffer` as:

```
<ShowOffer display={"block"} toggleVisibility={toggleVisibility} />
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, onClicks don't work as expected on components, they basically have to be on jsx elements?

Comment: It would be better to say that `onClick` will work on HTML elements not on `Custom component`. Because you are creating custom component which returns `JSX` i.e. HTML elements.

Comment: components are just functions which will return JSX, so setting `onClick` on the components is just passing as an argument to it so that you can attach `onClick` on the JSX that is returned from that function. I hope, It is clear now

Answer (score 1):

This is the simple logic. Your ShowOffer component is not identify the onclick event and this component's button is not have any event handlers. So you just pass the event or directly pass the function name for access the event. Passing props name is the important one.

```
<ShowOffer display={"block"} onClick = {toggleBox}/>
export default function ShowOffer({ display, onClick}) {
  return (
    <button style={{ display: `${display}` }} className="show-offer" onClick={onClick}>
      Show Offer
    </button>
  );
}
```

or

```
<ShowOffer display={"block"} toggleBoxFunct = {toggleBox}/>
    export default function ShowOffer({ display, toggleBoxFunct }) {
      return (
        <button style={{ display: `${display}` }} className="show-offer" onClick={toggleBoxFunct}>
          Show Offer
        </button>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use concept of Callbacks,
App.js, make following changes,
pass `toggleVisibility={toggleVisibility}` as props, no need to mention `onClick` at component but at button

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Modal display={modalVisible ? "flex" : "none"} />
      <ShowOffer display={"block"} onClick={toggleVisibility} toggleVisibility={toggleVisibility}/>
      <button onClick={toggleVisibility}>Button</button>
    </div>
  );
```

ShowOffer.js, props passed function, call that function here with `onclick`,

```
import React from "react";
import "./ShowOffer.css";

export default function ShowOffer({ display, toggleVisibility }) {
  return (
    <button style={{ display: `${display}` }} onClick={toggleVisibility} className="show-offer">
      Show Offer
    </button>
  );
}
```

working solution is here, https://codesandbox.io/embed/modal-overlay-tnis9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark